# Gallery displays Force Close Error

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I have created one application in which i have created gallery and below gallery i am displaying the selected image in zoom view...when i have more than 2 images then my gallery displays force close  error when i click on image from that.. I need help in this..

My Application code is:

```
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.GalleryView);

     DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
     getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);

     // set gallery to left side
    MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams) g.getLayoutParams();
    mlp.setMargins((int)-(metrics.widthPixels / 2 + 35), mlp.topMargin,mlp.rightMargin, mlp.bottomMargin);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this,imgarr);
    g.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    if(imgarr.length > 1)
    {       
        img.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imgarr[0]));          
    }
    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ImageGallery.this,
                    "Loading Image", "Please wait...", true);
            img.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imgarr[position]));               
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

 ImageAdapter class:
        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;
    String[] imgArray;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c,String[] imgArray) {
        mContext = c;
        TypedArray attr = mContext
                .obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.ImageGallery);
        mGalleryItemBackground = attr.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.ImageGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        this.imgArray = imgArray;
        attr.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return imgArray.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image path from gallery : " + imgArray[position],
        //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgArray[position]);
        Log.d("cursor lengh :", "" +imgArray[position]);
        //i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        i.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imgArray[position]));
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(80, 70));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
        return i;
    }
}
```

I have these errors:
[image]

Comment: Instead of pasting the logcat pic here, can you instead paste the logcat log itself? It'll be much helpful. Visibility issues. I can see only `OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget`, which means your bitmap is huge.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting error on this line.

```
   img.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imgarr[position]));
```

The error VM Budget indicates that the image is high resolution and the size is too large to accomodate.

Sol :  You need to cut down the size of your image.

You can use `inSampleSize` or `createScaledBitmap` or [this link](http://www.alonsoruibal.com/bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget/)

Also Understand how to use the view and release its memory for efficiancy.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: i m using inSampleSize while i m saving image to sdcard in onActivityResult method...and i have also tried the code of the link u have sent to me..but no change!! still this error is coming... My code is:
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 3;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);